# How to organize and separate EmberJS templates?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, single-page-application, code-organization

I started to use *EmberJS* a few months ago and have done some small sample projects to figure out how *EmberJS* works, but in all of these projects I have been by adding the templates directly to the `index.html` page.

**Yeoman**
I know about *Yeoman* and that it can compile your `.hbs` files to one file and that it provides a way for structuring your development.

**Internet Resources**
I checked a lot of resources on the internet on how to go about structuring *EmberJS* projects, but compared to *BackboneJS* resources are fewer, and the tutorials I do find do not provide an explicit answer.

**Question**
Are there best practices/conventions for organising your *EmberJS* templates other then using a tool like *Yeoman* that are provided and built into the framework itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Ember App Kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit), it gives you a good basic structure and some nice tools  to develop and build your Ember project. Stefan Penner who maintains the project is on the Ember Core Team and set this up to provide a good foundation for building apps with Ember.

I've been working on a large internal project since last summer and while our EAK-setup has changed a lot since then it still gave us a great start.

Comment: Hey Karl-Johan, thanks for your answer. I have been looking at that, it has the same approach as the Yeoman Ember generator. What I really want to know is: are there any conventions for this provided by the framework itself?

Comment: Ember doesn't really enforce much when it comes to templating. You can even replace handlebars with other templating systems if you want to. EAK was created by one of from the Ember Core Team to act as a good starting point and to provide a recommended way of doing things.

Comment: I ran into `Ember Cli` the successor of `Ember App Kit`. Thanks!